# How do I align my main slider to the left and hide the previous item in Swiper?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

How can i change the code below so i can  align my main slider to the left so i can see a slight smaller bit of the next item but not see any of the previous?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 jQuery(function($){

  var interval = setInterval(function () {

    if (typeof Swiper == "undefined") return;

    clearInterval(interval);
    const imageCarousel = jQuery ( '.hamasa22 .swiper-container' ),
    swiperInstance = imageCarousel.data( 'swiper' );
          
    swiperInstance.params.breakpoints[0].slidesPerView = 1.4;
    swiperInstance.params.breakpoints[0].centeredSlides = true;
    swiperInstance.currentBreakpoint = false;
    swiperInstance.params.isBeginning = true;
    swiperInstance.update();
    swiperInstance.updateSlides();
    swiperInstance.destroy(false, false);
    swiperInstance.init();



  }, 100);

 }); 
});
```

This is my current slider how it looks like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxNfE.png)

Thank you,

I tried this code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 jQuery(function($){

  var interval = setInterval(function () {

    if (typeof Swiper == "undefined") return;

    clearInterval(interval);
    const imageCarousel = jQuery ( '.hamasa22 .swiper-container' ),
    swiperInstance = imageCarousel.data( 'swiper' );
          
    swiperInstance.params.breakpoints[0].slidesPerView = 1.4;
    swiperInstance.params.breakpoints[0].centeredSlides = true;
    swiperInstance.currentBreakpoint = false;
    swiperInstance.params.isBeginning = true;
    swiperInstance.update();
    swiperInstance.updateSlides();
    swiperInstance.destroy(false, false);
    swiperInstance.init();



  }, 100);

 }); 
});
```

Comment: I have resolved the problem by just changing this to false :

swiperInstance.params.breakpoints[0].centeredSlides = false;